# Why is one cell lower than the rest?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using IE11 and this issue does not exist in FF or Chrome. It only exists in IE10/11 with resolution `1366x768`. Screenshot below shows the issue.

[image: Screenshot]

Here's my code on <kbd>[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pzbrno7/3/)</kbd>:

```html
<table class="rvTable" role="presentation" style="line-height:1.25;border-collapse: collapse; min-width: 460px; background-color: transparent;">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 151px;">
      <col style="width: 100px;">
        <col style="width: 56px;">

  </colgroup>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td style="border-width: 1px medium 1px 1px; border-style: solid none solid solid; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) currentColor rgb(0, 0, 0) rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 1px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <div class="rvParagraph pNormal" style="font-size: 13px;"><span class="rvTxt fNormal"><span class="forcedSpace"> </span><span class="forcedSpace"> </span>Years to</span><span class="xlPopupStep" data-dojo-attach-point="domNode" widgetId="PS5">
    <a name="PS5" tabindex="0" title="Definition" class="xlPopupLink" id="PS5" role="link" type="hyperlink" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode, focusNode" text="maturity">maturity</a>
    <span data-dojo-attach-point="_dummyTextHolder"></span>
          <div class="xlPopupStepPopup" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">
            LOADING...</div>

          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="border-width: 1px medium 1px 1px; border-style: solid none solid solid; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) currentColor rgb(0, 0, 0) rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 1px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <div class="rvParagraph pNormal_24" style="font-size: 13px;"><span class="eqLabel fNormal" id="Y1" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;" aria-label="30" widgetId="Y1"><span class="eqAccessibleLabel">30</span><span class="eqDocument" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"><span class="txtNum"><span>3</span><span>0</span></span>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="border-width: 1px 1px 1px medium; border-style: solid solid solid none; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) rgb(0, 0, 0) rgb(0, 0, 0) currentColor; padding: 1px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <div class="rvParagraph pNormal" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td style="border-width: 1px medium 1px 1px; border-style: solid none solid solid; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) currentColor rgb(0, 0, 0) rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 1px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <div class="rvParagraph pNormal_24" style="font-size: 13px;"><span class="eqLabel fNormal" id="Y2" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;" aria-label="20" widgetId="Y2"><span class="eqAccessibleLabel">20</span><span class="eqDocument" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"><span class="txtNum"><span>2</span><span>0</span></span>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="border-width: 1px 1px 1px medium; border-style: solid solid solid none; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) rgb(0, 0, 0) rgb(0, 0, 0) currentColor; padding: 1px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <div class="rvParagraph pNormal" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-width: 1px medium 1px 1px; border-style: solid none solid solid; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) currentColor rgb(0, 0, 0) rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 1px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <div class="rvParagraph pNormal" style="font-size: 13px;"><span class="rvTxt fNormal"><span class="forcedSpace"> </span><span class="forcedSpace"> </span>Price</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="border-width: 1px medium 1px 1px; border-style: solid none solid solid; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) currentColor rgb(0, 0, 0) rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 1px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <div class="rvParagraph pNormal_24" style="font-size: 13px;"><span class="rvTxt fNormal"><span class="wbr">​</span><span class="nowrap">?</span></span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="border-width: 1px 1px 1px medium; border-style: solid solid solid none; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) rgb(0, 0, 0) rgb(0, 0, 0) currentColor; padding: 1px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <div class="rvParagraph pNormal" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td style="border-width: 1px medium 1px 1px; border-style: solid none solid solid; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) currentColor rgb(0, 0, 0) rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 1px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <div class="rvParagraph pNormal_24" style="font-size: 13px;">
          <div class="nowrap"><span class="rvTxt fNormal"><span class="wbr">​</span><span class="nowrap">$</span></span><span class="eqLabel fNormal" id="BP2" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;" aria-label="2 comma 249.46" widgetId="BP2"><span class="eqAccessibleLabel">2 comma 249.46</span>
            <span
            class="eqDocument" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"><span class="txtNum"><span>2</span></span><span><span>,</span></span><span class="txtNum"><span>2</span><span>4</span><span>9</span><span>.</span><span>4</span><span>6</span></span>
              </span>
              </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="border-width: 1px 1px 1px medium; border-style: solid solid solid none; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) rgb(0, 0, 0) rgb(0, 0, 0) currentColor; padding: 1px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <div class="rvParagraph pNormal" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: I don't see that result on IE11. Not in [the original fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pzbrno7/2/), not in the Stack Snippet we copied it to for you.

Comment: Separately: Strongly recommend looking into using classes for styling rather than inline style attributes.

Comment: You may see the issue if you open this jsfiddle.net/2pzbrno7/3 in IE 10/11 with screen resolution 1366 X 768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my observation this is a browser issue and could solve by changing line-height.The current line-height is 1.25 and issue occurs only for values which can not be divided exactly by 2 . (eg: 1.23,1.25,1.27).

Answer (score 1):

It's because you don't have an explicit height declared on each cell of your table.

If you want to have the same design between your each cell used class and describe it in css.

you can used something near :

```
<td class="myCell">your content</td>
<td class="myCell">your second td</td>
```

and in a css part (stylesheet or tag) :

```
.myCell {
  height:1em;
}
```

Comment: I gave the height but issue still exists.

Comment: ok so your issue is strange but can have an explaination 1em is the text size so one cell filled the other not maybe there is a little différence. have you try putting all your css attributes in the class spécification? what happen if you put a size bigger? a height 100%?

Comment: There was a inherited property line-height:16px. I could resolve the problem by making it zero. What could be the issue ?

Comment: yes you are right you can select the line-height of your table by overiding this attribute. its a different attribute than the classical height and if the line-height is greater than the height you have an overflow  that you can manage with the attribute overflow. for sample to hide the overflow you can make overflow:hidden

Comment: You may see the issue if you open this jsfiddle.net/2pzbrno7/3 in IE 10/11 with screen resolution 1366 X 768

Answer (score 0):

The first cell has an exact height specified, and the second doesn't so it receives its naturally-occuring height. If you're counting on all browsers rendering fonts at the exact same size, you're gonna have a bad time. So either give both an explicit height or omit it from the first cell.

Comment: You may see the issue if you open this jsfiddle.net/2pzbrno7/3 in IE 10/11 with screen resolution 1366 X 768